# Loaded Bitmap doesn't scale to container size

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, imageview, size

I have a ListView Item that uses a Drawable as a default icon and am allowing an override if an icon is specified. When I load the Bitmap for the specified icon and set it to the ImageView that holds the default Drawable item, the size of the specified icon is far smaller.

Both the Drawable and the specified Icon are 128px x 128px so I "assumed" that they'd both be the same size upon loading.

Here's a screenshot of the problem.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Here is the XML for the ListItem:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/events1_lv1_listitem_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_default_text"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/events1_lv1_listitem_headline"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_default_text"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/events1_lv1_listitem_summary"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_default_text"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the snippet where I load the bitmap into the list item icon:

```
File headerImageFile = new File(src);
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(headerImageFile));
events1_lv1_listitem_icon.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid wrap_content. Set your images size to dp, and set scaleType to "fitXY". 
The following will do for you*

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/events1_lv1_listitem_icon"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_default_text"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't see your screen shot.

If your icon is 128px * 128px, you can set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` to 128px, then set the `scaleType` to `fitXY` or `centerCrop`. Like this:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/events1_lv1_listitem_icon"
        android:layout_width="128px"
        android:layout_height="128px"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_default_text"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar" />
```

As to the meaning of `scaleType`, you can see [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).